# Bizarre GUI repeat behavior

Tags: unity, vmware-workstation

So, when I restarted my 14.04 VMWare Workstation 9 image the other day, I am confronted with repeating narrow bands with the launcher showing multiple times.  It's not a display resolution issue.  Everything I do on the left is mirrored on the right.

[image: VMware screenshot: respeated screen]

Any ideas of what could cause this and how to rectify?  I don't reboot often, so I have absolutely no idea what update could have caused this.

Comment: `System settings > Displays > [ ] Mirror displays (...)` - is unset as it seems. Does VMWare have settings that might have effects here? Multidisplay options of some kind?

Comment: my next clue: anything over 800x600 causes this tiling effect.

Comment: Check the amount of RAM you have, both Graphics and internal - do you have enough to handle the task you try? Did you add something recently that "stole" some of it?

Comment: `top` reports plenty of free RAM on a 16GB VM, so no.

Comment: VMware is a company, which software exactly are you using: Player, Workstation, Fusion, etc?

Comment: Workstation 9, but I have found some other similar posts about other VMW products.  It's most likely an issue involving the display hardware emulation.  I think it's safe to assume Player and Fusion would be similarly affected because they use the same underlying engine.

Comment: Will Ubuntu be doing anything to resolve this so we can continue getting kernel updates?

Answer (score 3):

Definitely a kernel-related issue. I managed to fixed with:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.13.0-29-generic
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

This reverted me back to `3.13.0-24-generic`, which doesn't present the problem.

EDIT:
Upgrading the VM fixed it for me, permanently.  Currently running 3.13.0-39-generic with no more problems.

For more info, see this thread:
https://communities.vmware.com/thread/481038?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: The ...-29 kernel seems to have issues yes, I have experienced some. I could never log in - USB keyboard and mouse were "disconnected".

Answer (score 1):

This is still an issue with the `3.13.0-30-generic` kernel. For others still having this problem, use (after rebooting):

```
uname -r
```

to determine which version you recently updated to. Then remove the kernel in order to fallback to a previous version:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.13.0-30-generic
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

This reverted me back to `3.13.0-24-generic` and I no longer had the repeating launcher display.

**Note:** I'm using VMware's vSphere Client and my 32-bit Ubuntu is running in a VM version 7 virtual machine.