# Display bug on resolution > 800 / ubuntu 14 on VMware

Tags: 14.04, display, vmware

I moved a VM to a laptop  (1366x768). Now I have a problem with the resolution. Everything is ok on 800x600.

If I change the resolution to something higher than 800  (eg: 1024x768..), then, everything after the 800th pixel is  mirrored on the first 800 pixels.

Running a Linux 3.13.0-29-generic x86_64 x86_64  on VMware 6.0.2 
Everything updated (dist, package, vmware).

I tried 
 - to reconfigure xorg, re-install xorg.
 - different window manager, re-installed them,
 - playing with xrandr, 
 - uninstalling nvidia driver on hosting pc.

none of the above worked.

```
cvt 1024 768 60
# 1024x768 59.92 Hz (CVT 0.79M3) hsync: 47.82 kHz; pclk: 63.50 MHz
Modeline "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync



xrandr --verbose
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 800 x 600, maximum 3840 x 1920
default connected primary 800x600+0+0 (0x183) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x17d
    Timestamp:  403790
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
  1024x768 (0x17e)   47.2MHz
        h: width  1024 start    0 end    0 total 1024 skew    0 clock   46.1KHz
        v: height  768 start    0 end    0 total  768           clock   60.0Hz
  1024x768 (0x17f)   66.8MHz
        h: width  1024 start    0 end    0 total 1024 skew    0 clock   65.3KHz
        v: height  768 start    0 end    0 total  768           clock   85.0Hz
  1024x768 (0x180)   59.0MHz
        h: width  1024 start    0 end    0 total 1024 skew    0 clock   57.6KHz
        v: height  768 start    0 end    0 total  768           clock   75.0Hz
  1024x768 (0x181)   55.1MHz
        h: width  1024 start    0 end    0 total 1024 skew    0 clock   53.8KHz
        v: height  768 start    0 end    0 total  768           clock   70.0Hz
  1024x768 (0x182)    0.0MHz
        h: width  1024 start    0 end    0 total 1024 skew    0 clock    0.0KHz
        v: height  768 start    0 end    0 total  768           clock    0.0Hz
  800x600 (0x183)   28.8MHz *current
        h: width   800 start    0 end    0 total  800 skew    0 clock   36.0KHz
        v: height  600 start    0 end    0 total  600           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x184)   40.8MHz
        h: width   800 start    0 end    0 total  800 skew    0 clock   51.0KHz
        v: height  600 start    0 end    0 total  600           clock   85.0Hz
```

Any ideas on how to proceed? I 've spent 10 hours on this already, without success.

EDIT: I use VMWARE player

Comment: What VMware product you are using - [Player](https://www.vmware.com/products/player) or  Workstation?   Are VMWareTools installed?

Comment: What host OS are you using? Have you tried booting the VM under VirtualBox? Is the problem with this specific VM or other VMs too? If you create a new VM and boot the 14.04 ISO image on it do you get the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see https://askubuntu.com/a/484923/289138 - You're on `Linux 3.13.0-29-generic` -- as per the link, I suggest you downgrade to `linux 3.13.0-24-generic` (plausible fix), or check `linux 3.13.0-30-generic` also does the trick.

If the later ALSO is OK, the please tell us so.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from 3.13.0-30 and got the problem (at least I think). The problem was that resolutions above 800x600 were accepted, but did not the change the screen display. And the mouse no longer properly tracked locations on the screen. Reverting to 3.13.0-24 fixed it.